# How to set maximum time for an api call to return result using android volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using android volley for an api call. I am using the following retry policy:

```
new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            5000,
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT)
```

I understand the timeout we are setting for this retry policy is the SocketTimeout i.e the maximum time for which the data flow can be interrupted. Instead of this what I want is to set maximum time for an api call to return result. Is there a built in function for this in android volley or should I create a timer for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OkhttpCient, it has some methods

```
 client.setConnectTimeout (20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setWriteTimeout (120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setReadTimeout (40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));  /* control + click on DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES */

[image: Change the count here]